# Netbeans profiler OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.58.0.13-CA-macos-aarch64)

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

I am trying to use Netbeans 12.5 profiler on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.58.0.13-CA-macos-aarch64)

The first calibration process always fail.
Deleting ~/.nbprofiler doesn't fix the problem.

I am getting the error:
Profiler calibration data file does not exists:
/Users/myhome/.nbprofiler/machinedata.jdk18

and Netbeans output:

> *** Profiler message (Sun Jan 23 12:30:38 CET 2022): Starting target application...
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
> -agentpath:/Applications/NetBeans/Apache NetBeans 12.5.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/profiler/lib/deployed/jdk16/mac/libprofilerinterface.jnilib
> -Xbootclasspath/a:/Applications/NetBeans/Apache NetBeans 12.5.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/profiler/lib/jfluid-server.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/Apache
> NetBeans
> 12.5.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/profiler/lib/jfluid-server-15.jar
> org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server.ProfilerServer
> /Applications/NetBeans/Apache NetBeans
> 12.5.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/profiler/lib/deployed/jdk16/mac
> 5141 10 ****Profiler+Calibration+Run****
> *** Profiler warning (Sun Jan 23 12:33:11 CET 2022): timed out while trying to connect to the target JVM.
> *** Profiler error (Sun Jan 23 12:33:11 CET 2022): connection with server not open

My environment:

> Netbeans 12.5 openjdk version "1.8.0_312" OpenJDK Runtime Environment
> (Zulu 8.58.0.13-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 1.8.0_312-b07) OpenJDK 64-Bit
> Server VM (Zulu 8.58.0.13-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 25.312-b07, mixed
> mode) macOS 12.1 Chip Apple M1 Pro

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestion

Comment: It cannot connect to the JVM. Is there a recommended one you can try?

Comment: That is the problem. I don't know solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create your calibration file.

Navigate to the directory

```
cd ~/.nbprofiler
```

Then create the file `machinedata.jdk18`

```
touch machinedata.jdk18
```

And lastly, give the file `644` permission

```
chmod 644 machinedata.jdk18
```

Once you finish, you can run the profiler without errors.

Comment: it doesn't help: *** Profiler warning (Sat Dec 10 15:23:31 CET 2022): timed out while trying to connect to the target JVM. *** Profiler error (Sat Dec 10 15:23:31 CET 2022): connection with server not open

Comment: This question was posted 10 months ago. But have you tried updating your JVM to the latest version?

Comment: not working on jdk 17 and Netbeans 15. It's working on mac intel but not mac M1